# Simple way to obtain data from other programs?

Tags: c#, .net, data-transfer

Is there a simple way to fetch data from other programs running in the background? Like for instance i want my program to read the temperature values from Speed Fan and so on... So basicly reading data from controls that are present in a diffrent application.

Comment: There's probably a way, but it certainly won't be simple (unless those programs expose an API for you to query).

Answer (score 3):

For fan speed data you may have better luck with WMI, accessed through the [System.Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx) namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can comunicate programs by socket. For data transport you can use `XML` generated from `DataSet`.

---

You can use also `WM_COPYDATA`, for more information you can visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649011%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

---

Other way to do that is `Dynamic Data Exchange Management Library` or `Dynamic Data Exchange` if you don't support first option. For more information check: [DDEML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648712%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [DDE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648711%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

---

Other methods to implement **Interprocess Communications** you find at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574%28VS.85%29.aspx#base.using_data_copy_for_ipc